# Merging [character-set] and [charset]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-request

Both are about character sets, but they don't have any wiki

- [character-set](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/character-set) has only 8 questions
- [charset](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/charset) has 24 questions

I think [charset](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/charset) should be made a synonym of [character-set](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/character-set)

Comment: They should probably both be removed ...